# Eclipse autocomplete method variables

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, javadoc

I am calling a method in a class which has two parameters.

```
public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browserName, String URL)
```

I would like to use Eclipse's autocomplete to show me all the available variables. But it is only showing me browserName and null.

[image]

Is it possible to have chrome, firefox and ie to be included in the autocomplete list? On the other hand, I was trying to find ways to do this in javadoc but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the perfect solution you need to make an object with constants and use it like:

```
startBrowser(Browsers.IE, URL)
startBrowser(Browsers.Chrome, URL)
```

... etc